# Defining a finalizer in debug processor to locate any cases where Dispose was not called explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, destructor

Just wondering whether it is a right approach to define a finalizer in debug processor (as all the resources are managed resources, dont really need one) to locate callers if any, who are not invoking Dispose explcitly. And if so the finalizer would get called and raises Debug.Fail message.

```
Public class Foo: IDisposable
{
      ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
      Dispose(true);

      #if DEBUG         
      GC.SuppressFinalization();
      #endif
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing_)
    {
      if (disposing_)
      {
         // Unsubscribe from any event handlers, etc.
      }
    }

    #if DEBUG
    ~ Foo()
    {
      Dispose(false);
      Debug.Fail("Dispose was not invoked by caller"); // <--
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Afair there was an article on msdn about this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163324.aspx

Comment: Call of destructor is not depends whether the Disopse called explicitly or not. Call of Finalizers (destructors) is non-deterministic then they may be called never.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan could you explain in what kind of scenario a finalizer is never called (excluding power-loss and killed applications).

Comment: @Andreas Destroying the application domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, it is perfectly valid to have debuggable finalizers, msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163324.aspx – Andreas